# Contact form not sending email to my address

Tags: php, contact-form

I am having trouble with my contact form, the message isn't being sent to the email address I specified. Could anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here:

```
$emailTo = 'email@myemailwenthere.com';
$siteTitle = 'My sitename went here';

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // hide all basic notices from PHP

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // require a name from user
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError =  'Forgot your name!'; 
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    // need valid email
    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Forgot to enter in your e-mail address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'You entered an invalid email address.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    // we need at least some content
    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'You forgot to enter a message!';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    $subject = 'New message to ';
        $sendCopy = "";
        $body = "Name";
        $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$email.'>';

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    // upon no failure errors let's email now!
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $subject = 'New message to '.$siteTitle.' from '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        //Autorespond
        $respondSubject = 'Thank you for contacting '.$siteTitle;
        $respondBody = "Your message to $siteTitle has been delivered! \n\nWe will answer back as soon as possible.";
        $respondHeaders = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $emailTo;

        mail($email, $respondSubject, $respondBody, $respondHeaders);

        // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
        $emailSent = true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have your own SMTP server? Or does your web-hosting?

Comment: Does it send to any email address? How do you know the mail() function is being executed?

Comment: I don't see email to being assigned anywhere...  Perhaps you meant to do that instead of "email"  in your valid email checking?

Comment: 99.9% of the time it is a mail setup issue in php.ini.

Comment: does mail() return false? reccomend you try swiftmailer http://swiftmailer.org/ with a proper smtp server

Comment: I'm using dreamhost for web-hosting, do you think it's got to do with server config?

Comment: it doesn't send to any e-mail, although it does prompt me that message has been sent on the page.

Comment: may be you should check your spam box

Answer (score 0):

Try with a mini script to check or sending mail is possible:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did figure it out. It was a server setting issue with dreamhost. The code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try PHPMailer with SMTP configured, it gives lot of flexibility.

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)